# Есть такая функция, которая может перевести бинарный код в числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я знаю, что есть функция

```
bin(x)
```

Но она делает из числа - бинарный код.
Есть ли какой то способ перевода или нужно еще отдельно написать код для етого ???

Comment: под бинарным кодом имеется ввиду строка?

Comment: Так как "бинарный код" в заголовке двухсмысленный: может относится к строкам в двоичной системе (содержит только символы "01") так и к байтовым строкам (двоичные данные такие как картинка, архив). Первое как в теле вопроса: обратная к `bin()` операция это `int(bits,2)`. Второе: `int.from_bytes(b"\x73\x6f", 'big')==29551`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если под бинарным кодом вы имеете ввиду строку, то built-in функция [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) имеет необязательный аргумент `base`, который указывает, с каким основанием записано число в строке:

```
>>> bin(123)
'0b1111011'
>>> int('1111011', 2)
123
```